# Gmail Outlook IMAP - archive

Tags: microsoft-outlook, archiving, gmail-imap

I have an IMAP folder in Outlook synching with my Gmail account. I need to delete a lot of email from Gmail to free up space. However, I need to keep these deleted emails in my Outlook.

I assume I would have to move my Gmail emails in Outlook somewhere else and then delete delete emails in Gmail itself? If so, how can I do it? Or is there another way?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to remove the emails of Gmail account from sever?

If so, it's suggested that you could use AutoArchive. Referrences:
[Archive older items automatically](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-older-items-automatically-25f44f07-9b80-4107-841c-41dc38296667)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.

Comment: I tried to mark it but I am not allowed to as I have to have 15 reputations in order to do that. Also, yes I want to delete emails from Gmail. So, if I create the Archive folder in Outlook, will this be created outside the Gmail folder?

Comment: As i mentioned, the archive emails will be stored in a pst file in the path you choose.

Comment: I noticed that your reputation has exceeded 15, would you mind marking my reply as an answer？

Answer (score 1):

> I assume I would have to move my Gmail emails in Outlook somewhere
> else and then delete delete emails in Gmail itself?

Yes, you can do this. Use the Outlook Archive function (Outlook Settings), and make an Archive file (normally where the IMAP OST file is stored locally. If there is not an OST file, there should be an Outlook Folder in Documents. Put Archives there.

Once Archived, and for certain you have verified that the Archive has all the mail you want, then you can delete email in Gmail that you know is safely stored locally.

Back your Archive file up on two different computers so that the loss of one computer is not an issue.

Here is a screen shot of Outlook Archive basics.

You can see the settings to enable Archiving and the folder area where you can name the folder.

[image: Outook Archiving]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: You might consider marking my post as the answer.

Comment: I tried to mark it but I am not allowed to as I have to have 15 reputations in order to do that. I assume that I'll be able to choose the location of the Archive folder?

Comment: You can choose the folder you wish (see my screen shot - blow it up a bit if need be).  I use Documents\Outlook,